# How to drive two components with one engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How can I drive a compressor and a hp pump with one 13 hp engine. One at a time. The easyiest switch gear/ pulleys
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

The engine drives a shaft and pulleys drive belts to each machine then engage the pulleys or loosen and tighten the belts for drive.

Comment: Will abrasion of a pulley on a slack belt cause any long-term damage?

Comment: @DKNguyen seen flat belts that have been running for years… also had to learn how to replace them - there are different types of joint.